# For Loop with Index to Functional

Tags: functional-programming, swift

Trying to simply my code below:

```
for (index, point) in enumerate(self.points){
        let pointButton = UIButton()
        pointButton.frame = point.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(pointButton)
    }
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this through `.map` `.filter` or `.reduce` ?

Comment: you could, but honestly, having `self.view.addSubview()` removes any point of doing so because that is a side-effect. I don't know enough Swift to write this out, but you would want to use `map` over the `self.points` collection and have it return your `pointButton`, and then the mapped array as subviews.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please elaborate on the side-effect?

Comment: I'll try; basically, in FP, you generally strive to create 'pure functions' - they only operate on the arguments they are passed in, only interact with other pure functions, always return a value and they don't modify existing values/outside world. By having `self.view.addSubview()` in the function, you are causing a side effect because you are modifying the outside world (`self.view.addSubview()` stores state). Obviously every *useful program* uses state, but using map "just because" doesn't make it FP because of the reasons I've mentioned.

Comment: In reality there's likely a *nicer* way to write this using map, but you're going to have to separate this out into multiple functions and I just don't know enough swift (any) to do that. Maybe someone else will, I think we have a few swift users here

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate`if you're not using the index?

Comment: I'm using the index. Just now shown here in the code.

Comment: You should be using autolayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index` is not used at all, therefore you do not need `enumerate()`:

```
for point in self.points { ... }
```

(You mentioned in a *comment* that the index is used somewhere else,
but we can review only the code that is shown in your question.)

```
let pointButton = UIButton()
pointButton.frame = point.bounds
```

can be simplified to

```
let pointButton = UIButton(frame: point.bounds)
```

and then you could get rid of the intermediate variable:

```
for point in self.points {
    self.view.addSubview(UIButton(frame: point.bounds))
}
```

and this looks like the best solution in your case to me.

You *could* use `map()` for that purpose:

```
self.points.map {
    self.view.addSubview(UIButton(frame: $0.bounds))
}
```

But using `map()` for its side effects is frowned-upon, see for example
[Higher order function: “Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659616/higher-order-function-cannot-invoke-map-with-an-argument-list-of-type),
where an explicit `foreach` method is offered as an alternative:

```
extension Array {
    func foreach(function: T -> ()) {
        for elem in self {
            function(elem)
        }
    }
}
```

which can be used as

```
self.points.foreach {
    self.view.addSubview(UIButton(frame: $0.bounds))
}
```